# System.out.println for Java

Tags: java

How is it that `System.out.println(052)` and `System.out.println(0x2a)` both print 42?

Does this have to do with binary at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`052` is an [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base 8) literal.
`0x2a` is a [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (base 16) literal.

Comment: I see, thank you! So the exponents, they start with 0 to how ever many integers/letters are in the number , so in the case of 0x2a, the 16 is raised to the 3rd, then 2nd, then 1st, then to the zeroth power?

Answer (score 4):

`System.out.println(0x2a)` uses a *hex* literal (`0x` prefix indicates this), which has a decimal equivalent of `42`.

`System.out.println(052)` uses an *octal* literal (leading `0` indicates this), which has a decimal equivalent is `42`.

`System.out.println` will print the integers according to their decimal representation. If you want to keep hex, try `System.out.printf("%x\n", 0x2a)`, or, for octal, `"%o"` in place of `"%x"`.

Answer (score 2):

`052`, `0x2a` and `42` are all different ways of writing the (decimal, base *10*) number *42*:

- `052` is *octal*, or base *8*
- `0x2a` is *hexadecimal*, or base *16*
- `42` is the familiar *decimal*, base *10*

java allows you to use numbers literally in your code using any of these different formats: using a leading `0x` to specify hexadecimal, or a leading zero, `0` to specify octal.

This has to do with binary inasmuch as anything that you'll do with java has to do with binary.

By the way, the *binary*, base *2* representation of 42 is: `101010`. You can also use *binary* literals in java by preceding them with `0b`, so `0b101010 == 0x2a`.

Answer (score 1):

052, starts with 0, so it's an octal number and hence 8*5+2=42
0x2a starts with 0x, so it's a hexadecimal number and hence 16*2+a  = 32 + 10=42

Answer (score 1):

`052` is an octal literal, and is equivalent to `0 * 8^2 + 5 * 8^1 + 2 * 8^0`.
`0x2a` is a hexadecimal literal, equivalent to `2 * 16^1 + 10 * 16^0`.

`5 * 8 + 2` and `2 * 16 + 10` can be seen to be equivalent, as `5 * 8` is equivalent to `4 * 8 + 8`, and `8 + 2` equals `10`.